# Using iframe for an application in external websites

Tags: django, iframe

I have a website built in Django. One feature of this website is booking hotels. Now, my client has many agents who have websites. We want to give the facility of booking on these websites. So, I am thinking to use iframe on these websites( with the consent of the respective agent owners), which will point to the booking page of our website. Once booking is done, we will return success message and email the user. IS this a viable solution? Or, are there any other options?

thanks

Comment: Doing a rest api it's actually pretty simple. You just have to implement an url that receives a post(or a get) request, do something and return a response, usually json. It can be done using only django as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this it's creating a rest api using a helper that works with django like [django-piston](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-piston/0.2.1) so your agents could work with them to perform booking.

Should be easy to add a form to any agents site with this way. Or even using ajax if the uri returns a json.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will look into piston, and develop rest based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes is not the way you should go I think... I also think that you need to define the API on your website and then you just do requests from the client website to your backend.